# How can I get rid of horizontal padding or indent in html5 search inputs in webkit on mac?

Tags: css, html, search, input, padding

In webkit on mac only, the text in a search input is indented from the left side. [Here's a demo](http://oscorp.net/experiments/search-input/). Even after stripping all padding, text-indent, and setting `-webkit-appearance` to `textfield` or `none`, the text is still indented. It looks to be around 10px or so, but the inspector doesn't show any CSS rules (even browser defaults) that seem to apply this style. Any ideas?

```
<input type="search" value="Search">

-webkit-appearance: textfield;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-indent: 0;
```

Comment: I can't really reproduce this on Chrome: http://i.imgur.com/GjAZC.png

Comment: Interesting: here's what I see on mac chrome: http://cl.ly/212z0Y213k3z1D2V2H1k

Comment: This might be a platform-specific problem. On Linux, it works just fine.

Comment: You're absolutely right -- I checked chrome on PC, and there's no issue. I edited the title and description to reflect.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how you really reset the default styling in WebKit:

```
input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

After that the padding problem should be gone. If you also want to normalize the cancel button, which isn't there in non-WebKit browsers, add `input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button` as selector for the second rule.

Comment: Thanks -- if you look more carefully, you'll see that I've already got that applied, to no effect (well, not to no effect, it removed the rounded corners and stuff, but not the indenting)

Comment: No, you didn't and yes, I did watch carefully. Please add the rules I mentioned and you will see the padding is gone. You only declared  `-webkit-appearance: none;` on `input[type="search"]` (by using a 'webkitnone' class) but not on the mentioned pseudo element.

Comment: My apologies, you were completely right! I fixed the demo using your technique. Thank you for your help (and patience when I misunderstood).

Comment: This is so tricky! Thanks for straightening it out. I had previously only been hiding `-webkit-search-cancel-button`.

Answer (score 2):

By default WebKit-based browsers using border-box model for input[type="search"]. And if you using traditional box-sizing (you are if you haven't declared any other model) you may experience strange padding and border behavior. Fix:

```
input[type="search"] {
box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

As for `-webkit-appearance` - try `textarea` (`textfield`) and `none`.
In any case test your page on iOS device, to be sure that styling won't be different after input field being in focus (strange behavior, could be bug - i'm using iPhone 4S with stock iOS 6.0)