# Mysterious extra left padding on input[type="search"]

Tags: html, css

Anyone know what's causing this extra left 'padding' on the `input`? The inspector isn't reporting that anything is actually causing it. Can't say I've run into this issue before…

**The top field is a text `input` (search), the bottom field is a `select`**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Apparently the HTML code is the key to solving the problem, here you go:**

```
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
<select>
  <option value="ir35">IR35</option>
</select>
```

**Edit to add:**

I was a bit of a doofus, but the problem still remains. In experimenting with different input types I'd created two templates. The isse is actually on an `input[type="search"]` - NOT text. This is an issue with the search type. However I am already applying `-webkit-appearance: textfield` is there something else I'm missing? There's no actualy 'thing' causing the padding, text indent, padding, etc. It's just 'there'.

Edit:

My solution will be dropping search in favour of text - it's a workaround but it'll do.

Comment: Give us the html code

Comment: They're just form elements: <input type="text"/> and <select>

Comment: Is it happening in all your tested browsers? Each browser has its own bit of formatting added as default

Comment: @NathanHornby html code is is needed anyway if you want a correct response ...

Comment: I honestly can't imagine what use the HTML could be to you in ascertaining a solution to the problem. Do you mean the CSS?

Comment: @HanoJohannesRossouw same issue on all browser.

Comment: CSS can't create a whitespace. HTML can. (well, except if you have a `content:" ";` on a `::before` element)

Comment: There is no whitespace, as indicated by the image I included with the highlight.

Comment: Well, you can keep the css and the html for yourself. I'm not the one with the bug here ...

Comment: Check if browser adds perhaps text-indent on input fields

Comment: @Magus I'd rather not confuse the issue with irrelevant details. Should I also upload my htaccess file for you to review? :p

Comment: No text indent @HanoJohannesRossouw - I've also cleared default webkit styling from the element just to be sure.

Comment: Added the HTML, the light has been shone.

Comment: Try writing the padding explicitely for both items.. Maybe the default behaviour has different padding for the two different elements (and I think that the most important part of the code is in the CSS file..)

Comment: Both have manually set padding :(

Comment: You use bootstrap or something similar? The appearance seem different from the browser default appearance.

Comment: @GermanoPlebani That'll be the wonder of CSS.

Comment: Just added a correction, I have two templates which caused some confusion - this is an input type of search, not text!

Comment: You should have invested the time you used to write reasons to not present your html and css to make an actual [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and this problem would have been found on your side 20 minutes ago.

Comment: Haw haw, super clever. It was a simple request for info - the HTML would, and still doesn't shed any light on the problem. CSS request? That makes sense, but it hasn't been requested. If you don't want to input some help that's fine - but I'm, sick of rule fetishists on this site wasting everyones time for the sake of a bloody upvote.

Comment: You should step back and look at this request from a different perspective. You asked for help but did nothing to make your issue reproducible and acted arrogant against people who asked for resources to be able to help you. It's not a *rule* to post your code, but it should be common sense and good etiquette. In fact you are the one wasting peoples time like this. Good luck anyways.

Comment: Nobody has to engage in the question so I can't see how I'm wasting anyone's time - nobody is forced to be here. I have since provided the HTML code, it adds as much to the discussion as expected.

Answer (score 1):

`select` elements and `input` elements operate, I believe, under different box-models.

`box-sizing:border-box` is the default on `select` elements.

You can check this by looking in the "Computed Styles" when using Developer Tools

Setting `box-sizing:border-box` on both should fix it.

**DEMO Without**

```css
select,
input {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<select name='options'>
  <option value='option-1'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='option-2'>Option 2</option>
  <option value='option-3'>Option 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" />
```

**DEMO With**

```css
select, input {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<select name='options'>
  <option value='option-1'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='option-2'>Option 2</option>
  <option value='option-3'>Option 3</option>
</select>  

<input type="text" />
```

Comment: On chrome the snippet doesn't do what the author is asking... It fixes the widths of the two elements (in the first one the select is narrower) but the "padding" is not fixed

Comment: @Paulie_D I shamelessly re-purposed your snippet, thank you!

Comment: No hassle...happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

The styling of certain form elements like `input` and `select` is not specified in the CSS specification and is left up to the discretion of the browser developer, so there will be slight style variations across browsers.

In Firefox, you can make some hard-coded style adjustments to fix the padding issue that you are seeing.

For example, if you add `padding-left: 3px` to the input field, then the text value will line up with the option value displayed in the select box.

However, since padding cannot be negative, you can eliminate the left padding in the `select` element, though you can in the `option` element.

```css
select,
input {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
select {
  padding-left: 0px;
}
input {
  padding-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="Option 1" />

<select name='options'>
  <option value='option-1'>Option 1</option>
  <option value='option-2'>Option 2</option>
  <option value='option-3'>Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: But isn't that the purpose of `-webkit-appearance textfield `? To remove that browser styling? (at least in webkit browsers).

Comment: It's even the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127891/how-can-i-get-rid-of-horizontal-padding-or-indent-in-html5-search-inputs-in-webk but it's not solving the issue

Comment: My guess is that  `-webkit-appearance: textfield` may change the internal type of the element within the browser, but then, that element will respond to the default style sheet associated with the browser.

Comment: But there is no style being added - the computed style offers no information - shouldn't I be able to see what's causing the indent?

Comment: I think the form control element default styles are hard coded in the browsers and they would not appear using the inspection tools that come with the browsers (inspect element for example).  From a UX perspective, I think this is a material limitation and your best hope is to work around it using padding.  Your question is probing, which is good, but also touches a subject area that is hard to answer satisfactorily.

Comment: I'm just going to fallback to using a text input, I prefer to use semantic elements but if the browser makers are going to make them difficult to work with there's not much that can be done.

Comment: Keep in mind that CSS3 has come a long way in ten years, and browsers are very much improved over the same period, we do live in exciting times from a technology point, all the best!

Comment: It certainly has Marc! What we could do 10-15 years ago pails in comparison. But it's a shame that there are semantic elements that we don't actually have style control over - I think that's browser over-reach.